# ¿Cómo almacenar el nombre de una SESION PHP en BBDD MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, post, session

Hola estoy realizando un programa de gestión de tareas.

- Un usuario de loguea y accede a un perfil.
- Desde el archivo **profile.php** se comprueba que se ha iniciado una sesión y saluda al usuario usando la variable **$_SESSION["username"]**.
- Una vez en perfil, el usuario puede crear diferentes tareas a través de un formulario que llama a un archivo llamado **add.php** que se encarga de almacenar la información correspondiente a las tareas en una BBDD MySQL.
- No obstante, me gustaría poder almacenar también en la BBDD el nombre de usuario, es decir, la variable **$_SESSION["username"]** de la persona que introdujo esa tarea. Mi objetivo es poder vincular de alguna manera las tareas con los usuarios.
- En la BBDD MySQL tanto la tabla usuarios como la tabla tareas cuentan con un campo **username**.

Adjunto los códigos tanto del archivo correspondiente al perfil como del archivo correspondiente a agregar las tareas en la BBDD.

Agradecería mucho una ayuda. Un saludo.

**ARCHIVO PROFILE.PHP**

```
<?php
  
session_start();
 
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
  header("location: login.php");

  exit;
}

    require_once "config2.php";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Kanban</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesión</a>

    <div class="main-section">
    <header>
      <h1>Hola <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></h1>
    </header>
        <div class="add-section">
            <form action="app/add.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                <?php if(isset($_GET['mess']) && $_GET['mess'] == 'error') { ?>
                    <input type="text" 
                           name="title" 
                           style="border-color: #ff6666"
                           placeholder="Debes introducir un proyecto">
                    <button type="submit">Crear &nbsp; </button>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <input type="text" 
                           name="title" 
                           placeholder="Introduce un proyecto">
                    <button type="submit">Crear &nbsp; </button>
                <?php }?>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**ARCHIVO ADD.PHP**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['title'])){

    require '../config2.php';

    $title = $_POST['title'];

    if(empty($title)){
        header("Location: ../profile.php?mess=error");
    }else {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO todos(title) VALUE(?)");
        $res = $stmt->execute([$title]);

        if($res){
            header("Location: ../profile.php?mess=success");
        }else {
            header("Location: ../profile.php");
        }
        $conn = null;
        exit();
    }
}else {
    header("Location: ../profile.php?mess=error");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría, primero que nada almacenar en la tabla `todos` el id del usuario más que el username y hacerlo una FK ([Clave foránea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_for%C3%A1nea)).

Del mismo modo, tal vez te convenga almacenar, además del username para saludar, el id del usuario logeado.

Y al momento de hacer la inserción de la tarea puedes usar algo como:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO todos(title, owner_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
$res = $stmt->execute([$title, $_SESSION['user_id']]);
```

Comment: Tienes razón, es mucho mejor almacenar el ID del usuario. De hecho también lo tengo almacenado en otra variable de sesión.  Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @NickTiery no hay problema amigo! Me alegra que te haya servido ;)